# How do migrations affect the schema.rb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am a little confused how **migrations** affect **schema.rb** file?

For example if I write a migration to rename a table column and run that migratin and even do a `schema:load rake task` too, then when I open my `schema.rb` file should it **automatically** be changed to have that new column name? or should I manually change it in there too?

**Also** my **create_table*.rb** files that create the original tables. They automatically have a `t.timestamp field` defined in them that creates those two `created_at` and `updated_at` fields in the schema, so if I want to remove those is it enough to just alter the create_table*.rb file and take out `t.timestamp` from them? and run the migration? or again I should manually alter shcema.rb file too?

So if someone can explain a little bit how there work together would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The schema file is automatically altered when you run migrations. You should never have to manually edit it.

See [this Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you) for moer information.